# CW complex from the fundamental polygon

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Is there any way to get the CW complex structure from the fundamental polygon.I am having problem in finding the CW complex structure of objects which cant be visualized?

Comment: A CW complex structure is something defined on a topological space, so I must ask: What topological space are you asking about?

Comment: For example I know the fundamental polygon for Klein bottle.So how do I get the CW structure from it?

Comment: @LeeMosher I saw your answer here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418311/cw-complex-structure-and-intuitive-construction-of-spaces  Can we do the same thing for Klein bottle?

Comment: Yes, that's right (I forgot about that answer).

Comment: @LeeMosher But do we need to cut through the diagonal(as done in Hatcher page 51) .I dont understand  what purpose it serves.

Comment: A space in general does not have a unique CW complex structure. If you just want one structure, you already know how to do it. If you want another, different structure, you can cut through the diagonal. And there are still more CW structures. But this gets beyond your question.

Comment: @LeeMosher  Does this mean that if we have a fundamental polygon we can get CW structure with only 1-2 skeleton.?