# What is wrong with my computation of the boundary map of the $2$-cell in the torus's CW structure, $d_2(e^2_1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm a bit confused with the computation of the boundary in cell complexes. I'm trying to compute the boundary of $e^2$ in the torus (as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418311/cw-complex-structure-and-intuitive-construction-of-spaces)), which, by merely looking at the leftmost picture, should turn out to be $b+a-b-a$ (starting from the bottom left corner, counter-clockwise). Doing this formally (using Hatcher's formula on p. 140 in *Algebraic Topology*:  $d_n(e_n) = \sum_\beta d_{\alpha\beta} e^{n-1}_\beta$, I've come up with the following):

Denote by:

$$ \phi^1_1 : \partial D^1 \to S^0 $$
$$ \phi^1_2 : \partial D^1 \to S^0 $$
$$ \phi^2_1 : \partial D^2 \to S^1 $$

the attaching maps for: the $1$-cell $e^1_{\phi_a}$ that forms the loop $a$ in the torus (see right-hand-side image in aforementioned post), the $1$-cell that forms the loop $b$ in the torus and the attaching map for the only $2$-cell. (NOTE: perhaps my confusion lies here, since (according to the definition of CW complexes in Hatcher's book, p. 14) I've constructed only one map $\phi^2_1$ from the $2$-cell to $S^1$, but there is one for each edge..?).

And now I get:

$d_2(e^2_1)=d_{11}e^1_1 d_{12}e^1_2 = 1a+1b = a+b$

Where did I go wrong that I'm missing the $-a -b$ part? There are only two attaching maps in dimension $1$ (i.e., we should only have two indices for $\beta$). Does $d_{11}$ perhaps split into two parts? Or did I get the CW complex definition wrong, and I'm allowed to have multiple 'sub-attaching-maps' per map (i.e. $\phi^2_1$ can actually turn into $4$ maps)?

Also - just to make sure I got this, in reality we're taking the boundary of a singular $2$-simplex here, right? (Hatcher writes: "we are identifying the cells $e^n$ and $e^{n−1}$
with generators of the corresponding summands of the cellular chain groups." (Although a clarification on what these summands are exactly would be great).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first suggest that to get a fuller picture of the notation and mathematical details of CW complexes you should also read Hatcher's Appendix entitled *Topology of Cell Complexes*.

There is indeed only one attaching map per cell, and your notation for those maps is fine.

But your formula for $d_2$ is wrong. What would greatly help in deriving the correct formula are the following:

1. Good notation for the characteristic maps of $e^1_1$ and $e^1_2$.
2. Application of those characteristic maps to write down a good formula for $\phi^2_1$.
3. Application of that formula to derive the correct formula for $d_2$.

For item 1, following the notation from Hatcher's appendix let me use $\Phi^1_1, \Phi^1_2 : D^1 \to X^2$ to denote the characteristic maps for $e^1_1$ and $e^1_2$.

For item 2, using $D^1 = [0,1]$ and thinking of $\Phi^1_1$ and $\Phi^1_2$ as paths, one can write a concatenation formula for the attaching map $\phi^2_1$:
$$\phi^2_1 = \Phi^1_2 * \Phi^1_1 * \overline{\Phi^1_2} * \overline{\Phi^1_1}
$$
where $*$ is the path concatenation operator, and $\overline\Phi$ is the path inversion operator, $\overline\Phi(t)=\Phi(1-t)$.

By the way there is the usual abuse of notation going in this formula for $\phi^2_1$: the formula defines $\phi^2_1$ as a closed path, i.e. a function with domain $[0,1]$ such that $\phi^2_1(0)=\phi^2_2(1)$. But then one should really convert it into a formula with domain $S^1$, by using the usual parameterization for $S^1$ given by the formula $(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$, $t \in [0,1]$.

Finally, for 3 one should write something like this:
\begin{align*}
d_2(e^2_1) &= \text{degree}(\Phi^2_1) + \text{degree}(\overline{\Phi^2_1}) = 1 + (-1) = 0 \\
d_2(e^2_2) &= \text{degree}(\Phi^2_2) + \text{degree}(\overline{\Phi^2_2}) = 1 + (-1) = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: It might help the op if you say why sending $e^2_1$ through the quotient machinery means we consider $d_2(e^2_1)$ in terms of $\Phi^2_1,\,\overline{\Phi^2_1}$ and these maps only. I haven't studied it properly but I know my main source of confusion with cellular homology is how to handle the incidence relations in the quotient rigorously and carefully

Comment: Is $\text{degree}(\Phi^2_1)$ in Hatcher's notation $\Delta_11$ (from p. 141 where he proves the boundary formula)? Also, why $e^2_2$?

Comment: It would actually be quite helpful if all of this were defined using the terms Hatcher himself uses ($\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$ being "the attaching map of $e^n_\alpha$ followed by the quotient map $X^{n−1}\to S^{n−1}_\beta$ collapsing the complement of
$e^{n−1}_\beta$ in $X^{n−1}$ to a point" (If I'm not mistaken, $d_{\alpha\beta}$ is the degree of this map)). I'll try to see if I can reconcile what you've written with that - then I might be able to understand your suggestion better. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have to add more later to address your latest point regarding $\Delta_{\alpha\beta}$, but for now I'll say quickly that this is related to the "abuse of notation" in my answer: $d_2(e^2_1)$ is the degree of the "circle-to-circle" map obtained by replacing the domain of $\Phi^2_1$ with $S^1$, and replacing its range $X^1$ with the quotient circle obtained by collapsing to a point all of $X^1$ except the interior of $e^2_1$. This circle-to-circle map consists of one forward wrap around the image circle followed by one backward wrap around the image circle.

Comment: OK - I think I got it - would love to hear your thoughts: Let $\Delta_{11}$ be as Hatcher defines, where, in our case, the first $1$ pertains to $\phi^2_1$ and the second $1$ pertains to $\phi^1_1$, so that $\Delta_{11} : S^1 \to S^1$. Then $deg(\Delta_{11})=1-1$ (since we can use the sum of local degrees as such: we can find a $y \in S^1$ with two $x_i \in S^1$, one per edges, that have disjoint nbhds homeomorphic to an open nbhd around $y$, and due to orientation, the $x$ from the bottom edge contributes $+1$ and the $x$ from the top $-1$ --[is there an easier way?]) and..

Comment: Yup, that sounds correct.

Comment: ...similarly we get $deg(\Delta_{12})=1-1$ from the other edges (marked $a$), so that in total we have: $d_2(e^2_1)=deg(\Delta_{11})b + deg(\Delta_{12})a=(1-1)b+(1-1)a=b-b+a-a$, which is in line with what you wrote at the bottom. Did I get it? Is there perhaps an easier way to say what $deg(\Delta_{11})$ and $deg(\Delta_{12})$ are than by using the sum of local degrees? Or is this the way to go about it (besides observing that there is a single wraparound, intuitively)?

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The whole "sum of local degrees" is really the key idea here. I don't think anything simpler is needed, on top of which that's really the same idea that is used in differential topology to do practical computation of degrees of maps $S^n \mapsto S^n$ or more generally maps between compact oriented manifolds of equal dimension.